# Detect Distance/Proximity Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to make an app using phone sensor, similar to something happen when you are on phone call and the sensor covered and the device screen turned off. Is there any API available to access that sensor? thx

Answer (score 1):

You have the `LightSensor` class available as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.sensors.lightsensor.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: thx for your answer, I did some more research and come up with this article, which contains exact API I need, but it only available on windows 10 for now.

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/8656870-provide-api-proximity-sensor

Comment: And like your tag suggests, you're looking for Windows 8.1 right? The API I provided can be worked to act like the API you linked.

Comment: Yes I need 8.1 version, I have been using light sensor for a while, the problem with using light sensor is the sensitivity on low light condition is not good. I dont know what sensor they are using for the windows 10 proximity API, maybe different for each device, but it works great under low light environment compare to lightsensor API.